# Resistor selection

Tags: resistors, relay, current-signal

I need help on what resistor (if any) I need for this set up.
12v car power as signal power to DPDT relay switch. What do I need on the deadend side of relay signal?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t0Oa.png]

Answer (score 5):

If it's a 12V DC relay you don't need a resistor!